# How to change uim IME input method using command-line OR programmatically?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout, input

The `uim` package provides different input methods like `direct` (None, use X keyboard mapping), `beyeoru` (Korean), `anthy` (Japanese).

It also provides several GUI tools for switching input methods (e.g. tray applet, toolbar, etc). You can also configure a hot-key for switching between two inputs (e.g. `direct` and `beyeoru`).

How can I command-line or programmatically switch between these input methods [`direct`, `beyeoru`, `anthy`] without the use of a hotkey or GUI?

Comment: Check out the [xdotool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xdotool) package.

Comment: It may be possible via `dbus`. I personally use `fcitx` , and did write python script for that , so it may be possible to do the same for `uim`.   I've never used it though, so will need to set it up first.

Comment: It does not seem to use `dbus`. I thought about `xdotool` but I actually think it might only be possible to toggle between the IME and `direct` rather than between altogether different IMEs (e.g. japanese to korean). 1/x

Comment: This Python script monitors the relevant socket file that the GTK widgets communicate with. I had earlier tried to send to the socket using sensible parameters but could not get it work. https://github.com/kiike/scripts/blob/master/uim-eye.py

Comment: Finally... I am having success rolling my own C program based off of `libuim` and examples. May refactor to parse CLI args and make a P/R.

Comment: @pztrick Please post a link to your program!

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev It has been a very long time since I grokked `uim` but here is the source: https://gist.github.com/pztrick/028ecf0df7ad68d0173d2ec7bd6b84d8 I also remember having to edit some `/usr/share` and `$HOME/.uim.d` configs for my use case. Sample usage: `/my/bin/uim-switch-im pinyin-big5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distil what the toolbar apps and libuim are doing:

```
action=im_change_whole_desktop
input_method=anthy
printf "%s\n%s\n\n" "$action" "$input_method" | \
    nc -NU "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/uim/socket/uim-helper"
```

If you use a non-XDG distribution/environment, the socket will be in `~/.uim.d/socket/uim-helper` instead.

`$action` can be `im_change_whole_desktop`, `im_change_this_application_only` or `im_change_this_text_area_only`.

To get a list of input methods, you can run `uim-sh -e installed-im-list`.

Comment: Accepting this as it appears correct but won't be able to test now, a year later. :) See OP comments for source to a program that may be useful to someone in the future...